# Is there Sustainsys.Saml2 example for ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, saml, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I try to SAML with Sustainsys.Saml2. I downloaded and run examples from their [Github](https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2) page. But all examples for ASP.NET MVC.

I develop my site with ASP.Net Web Forms. My site is service provider for SAML. I changed my web config as [in the example](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/2.0/configuration.html) but I can't redirect my login page to identity provider's login page.

Comment: did you get this working? I'm doing the same, on a legacy ASP.Net Web Forms app.

Comment: got it. My issue was my UrlRewrites

Answer (score 0):

The HttpModule sample is set up in the same way as a Web Forms app should be set up.